# How to write the 3- address mode instruction if we have question like this z=y*u*(a+e)+w*a+e

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture

if I'm following the BODMAS rule then

```
add x,a,e
mul v,x,u
mul g,v,y
mul o,w,a
add q,o,g
add z,q,e
```

Is this right? if not then what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it is the first time I hear from this rule, but I still want to share my thoughts :)

**B***rackets first*

**O***rders*  `n/a`

**D***ivision* and **M***ultiplication*  (left to right)

**A***ddition* and **S***ubtraction* (left to right)

I think your only "problem" here is that you don't respect the **left to right** rule. In general this should apply to everything.

So it should be:

```
x=a+b  |   add x a b
z=y*u  |   mul z y u
v=z*x  |   mul v z x
o=w*a  |   mul o w a
q=v+o  |   add q v o
z=q+b  |   add z q b
```

Comment: I thought the same. BODMAS, huh? Nice answer.

Comment: I guess BODMASLTR wasn't catchy enough